# Retrieving value of options flags from curl command in Flask

Tags: python, http, flask, curl

I'm sending a curl command to a HTTP Flask server I've created. The command I'm sending is as follows:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @africa-toto.wav http://localhost:5000/
```

Is there a way to parse the actual name of the file from this command using Flask (i.e. "africa-toto.wav")? I can receive the binary data just fine, but I'm not able to find the actual filename referenced in any of the attributes of Flask's *request* object

I have tried checking *request.files*, and a few others, but no filenames seem to be getting stored anywhere

Comment: You're not using `curl` correctly. It should be `--data upload=@africa-toto.wav`. Then you can get the filename from `request.files["upload"].filename`.

Comment: See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/fileuploads/